# 'true' is being shown when SWT Radio Button is clicked while UFT automation testing

Tags: testing, automation, swt, eclipse-rcp, hp-uft

We have a dialog, where we use table viewer and in one of the columns, we used a Boolean data which are shown in the form of radio buttons. While running an UFT based automation suite which clicks the radio button and also encounters a confirmation dialog and clicks some other radio button again. In that above process we encounter the issue which is not possible to encounter while testing manually.

[image: Image of radio button overlapping 'true' text]

I would like to know what the issue might be.
Let me know if there is a way to fix it.

Comment: *How* is it clicking that radio button, exactly?

Comment: Set obj = Eval("JavaWindow(""Application"")." &JavaMethod&"("""&Widget&""")")
obj.click

Click is done with the above lines.